# Problem with converting a string to an integer and passing as an ID to a view

Tags: java, android

There are 20 buttons in an Activity .

The ids are `R.id.ButtonR1C1; R.id.ButtonR1C2` .. and so on ie. Row 1, Col 1..

now earlier I had created 20 buttons.

```
private Button b1,b2,b3...;
```

and then

```
b1=(Button)findViewbyId(R.id.ButtonR1C1);
b2=(Button)findViewbyId(R.id.ButtonR1C2);
```

.... and so on.

Finally

```
b1.setOnClickListener(this);
b2.setOnClickListener(this);
```

... 20

so I thought I'd create a Button Array

```
Button barray[][]=new Button{4][5];
for(int i=1;i<=4;i++) {
   for (int j=1;j<=5;j++) {
      String t="R.id.ButtonR"+i+"C"+j;
      barray[i-1][j-1]=(Button)findViewbyId(Integer.parseInt(t));
   }
}
```

Gives an error..

Any help??

Comment: @willcodejavaforfood I missed to read Question correctly :)

Answer (score 1):

If you have copied your code directly, your syntax is wrong.

```
Button barray[][]=new Button{4][5];
```

should be

```
Button barray[][]=new Button[4][5];
```

**Note the curly bracket instead of square bracket before the 4.**

Your next problem, is that you are trying to get the value of R.id.something, but you only have the string representation of it. So, the only way I know to do this is using reflection.

What you need to do is,

```
Button barray[][]=new Button{4][5];
for(int i=1;i<=4;i++) {
   for (int j=1;j<=5;j++) {
      Class rId = R.id.getClass();
      // this gets the id from the R.id object.
      int id = rId.getField("ButtonR"+i+"C"+j).getInt(R.id);
      barray[i-1][j-1]=(Button)findViewbyId(id);
   }
}
```

Comment: I don't know andriod but what this `{` means?

Answer (score 0):

```
String t="R.id.ButtonR"+i+"C"+j;
Integer.parseInt(t);
```

This part of your code will definitly throw a runtime exception, because `t` does not contain a numeric value.

I don't know the format/value of your ID values, but this *might* work:

```
Button barray[][]=new Button[4][5];      // type corrected
for(int i=1; i<4; i++) {                   // changed the for loop...
   for (int j=1; j<5; j++) {               // changed the for loop...
      String t="R.id.ButtonR"+i+"C"+j;
      barray[i-1][j-1]=(Button)findViewbyId(t);  // t *is* the id (?)
   }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The Problem is here:

```
String t="R.id.ButtonR"+i+"C"+j;
barray[i-1][j-1]=(Button)findViewbyId(Integer.parseInt(t));
```

You're trying to convert a String `t` to an `Integer` (while the String is not numeric at all).
This will result in [`NumberFormatException`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/NumberFormatException.html). You should make sure that `t` is **absolutely** numeric.

Answer (score 0):

I used this code:

```
Class c = Class.forName("com.test.R$id");
Integer i = new Integer(c.getField("ToolsbuttonR3C4").getInt(new R.id()));
System.out.println("HEXA="+i.toHexString(i));
```

and the ids are in sequential order. so it can be done.

Thanks ppl

Answer (score -1):

So you are trying to convert the String "R.id.ButtonR1C1" to a NUMBER...

That will most certainly give you a NumberFormatException since it is CLEARLY NOT A NUMBER! :)

Comment: R.id.ButtonR1C1 is an integer in android.

Comment: @Abhishek susarla - No it's a String, hence the "" that surrounds it

Comment: @Abhishek susarla - I'll write you down as a lost cause :)

Comment: @willcodejavaforfood R.id.ButtonR1C1 is an int, "R.id.ButtonR1C1" is a string. He's trying to convert the string to the int that R.id.ButtonR1C1 represents.